# ASP.NET Ajax is removing javascript function defined on onclick attribute after partial postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, partial-postback

We have a CheckboxList & each item of this CheckboxList has one javascript function (clearcheckboxes()) defined for onclick attribute.

This CheckboxList is inside the UpdatePanel & Trigger is defined for this as well.

On the initial Page Load, I can see the defined javascript function on the each list item as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="0" onclick="javascript:clearcheckboxes('page_0_chbxList',this.id);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'page_0$chbxList$0\',\'\')', 0)" checked="checked" name="page_0$chbxList$0" id="page_0_chbxJobList_0">
```

But when I select any checkbox & page get partially reload it removes the javascript function from onclick attribute :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'page_0$chbxList$2\',\'\')', 0)" checked="checked" name="page_0$chbxList$2" id="page_0_chbxList_2">
```

How we can prevent removal our custom onclick javascript function on partial postback?

Comment: try moving inline onclick functions to a fixed one

Comment: how do you bind the onclick events, are you rebinding it after the ajax has fired?

Comment: @Pete onclick attribute is added via C# code & yes we are rebinding CheckboxList control after ajax.